# Debugging whether Bolt requests make it to Neo4j

Tags: java, debugging, neo4j, log4j, slf4j

I'm trying to work out whether bolt requests are making it to neo4j. I saw [this commit to neo4j](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/commit/87e5046a9463175d65b9c9b084085fcbaaae746f) but it's not entirely clear to me how to enable that debug logging since there's no `log4j.properties` in neo4j's directories and no slf4j jar..

Can someone help me turn on some sort of logging that'll let me debug bolt issues?

Chris